# how to get gav(groupId, artifactId, version) info from a gradle jar (it is no contains pom.xml)?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have some **gradle jars**, I want to get **gav** info from them. but they are no contains `pom.xml` or `pom.properties`. I not found any file contains **gav** info. Example:

[image: spring-boot]

[image: okhttp3]

Comment: Usually, the `pom.xml` is below the directory representing the groupId, so have you looked inside the `org` directory as well?

Comment: This is a jar which is not packaged by Maven so will not find a `pom.xml` in `META-INF/maven/` because it does not exist. This means in the end there is not `pom.xml` or `pom.properties` within the jar.  The other question is here: Why do you need them? Either you use Maven / Gradle in both cases you have defined them?